# Change Font Size dynamically based on Character count

Tags: jquery, css, count, character, string-length

I'm trying to adjust title sizes depending on character length. (wordpress)

This is what I have so far. It doesn't return any error but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        var textLength = $('.autotitle').val().length;
        if (textLength < 20) {
            // Do noting 
        } else if (textLength > 20) {
            $('.autotitle').css('font-size', '16px');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you have if condition if you do nothing .. put else condition directly.

Comment: What kind of html element is `.autotitle` ? If it's not `input` try `.html()` instead of `.val()` but note that it may include inner tags and whitespaces.

Comment: .autotitle refers to a class. I changed it into this. Now it changes every .autotitle class div without counting characters

Comment: `code`jQuery(function ($) {
        $(window).load(function() { 

var textLength = $(".autotitle").val().length;
  
  if(textLength < 20) {
      $(".autotitle").css('font-size', '12px');
  }
});
}); `code`

Comment: actually, it counts and works, but it applies css to all the elements with that class. How can I apply it only to the ones that fit into the count?

Answer (score 4):

Many times one would like to decrease font size (make it smaller) when text is long based on letter count
(text might have been entered through some CMS or translated text)

http://jsfiddle.net/jfbrLjt2/

```
 $('.text').each(function(){
     var el= $(this);
       var textLength = el.html().length;
        if (textLength > 20) {
            el.css('font-size', '0.8em');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/125/)  use `html` instead of using `val`

```
       var textLength = $('.autotitle').html().length;
```

Comment: both .val and .html work now, but it changes all the .autotitle elements instead of only the ones that fit into the count

Comment: use this , `$(".autotitle:first").html()`

Answer (score 0):

solved it with a php function

```
function trim_title() {
$title = get_the_title();
$limit = "14";

if(strlen($title) <= $limit) {
echo $title;
} else {
echo '<span class="longtitle">'; echo $title; echo '</span>';
}
}
```

thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If u use `.autotitle` then changes will be applied to every element where u use `.autotitle` as `class` attribute ...

Instead that u can use `id` attribute of particular element to apply changes to only that element

Ex :

`$('#id').css('font-size','16px');`