# Decrease font size according to text length

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my laravel project view file, I’m displaying some text inside div which getting from table.

Now i need to decrease the font size of text if it is too long.

I need to do it using pure js (without jquery or other thing)

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically changing the size of font size based on text length using css and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229230/dynamically-changing-the-size-of-font-size-based-on-text-length-using-css-and-ht) 

Check for the second most upvoted answer.

Comment: @Johannes is it possible do this with only css and html?